# Is there an error in this javascript/jquery script?

Tags: javascript

EDIT: FIXED! Thanks a lot!

I am getting this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

This small script is causing it :(
Are there any errors in it? Thanks

```
    <script language="javascript">
    document.onmousedown=disableclick;
    status="Right Click Disabled";
    Function disableclick(event)
    {
      if(event.button==2)
       {
         alert(status);
         return false;    
       }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Function keyword should be small letter as function

Comment: Put the entire `disableclick` above 1st line...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging which is not purpose of SO. Learn how to debug javascript code

Comment: don't use language. use type instead <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: Thanks Bhushan Kawadkar!! The error has been fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct code below:

```
document.onmousedown=disableclick;
    var status="Right Click Disabled";
    function disableclick(event)
    {
      if(event.button==2)
       {
         alert(status);
         return false;    
       }
    }
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLgp6/)